# How to insert a Label and an image icon into the Menu bar of a netbeans platform application

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-platform

In my netbeans platform based app, I need to add a Label which shows the user name and a image icon into the Menu bar. Menu items are defined in an xml file and action classes are used to define menu actions. How can I customize the menu bar in order to put a label and a image icon at the right corner of the menu bar? Is this possible?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this is given in forum post :
[http://forums.netbeans.org/post-140363.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20151019040537/http://forums.netbeans.org:80/post-140363.html)